# animation delay without queue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I have a little problem with animation in jquery.

This is my code :

```
$(function()
{
    var speed = 1000;
    var target = -878;
    var pause = 7000;
    var rewind = 300;
    var fullPause = 99999999;

    setInterval(function()
    {
        $(".slideshow ul").animate({marginLeft:target},speed,function()
        {
            $(".slideshow ul").hover(function() {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, rewind).delay(fullPause);
            }, function() {
                $(this).animate({ }, speed); //restart
            });

            $(this).css({marginLeft:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        })
    }, pause)
};
```

This almost work. The problem is during the pause, animation continuer in queue and when the mouse leave my div, animation make all the steps missed.

Is it possible to break the timeout ? or using a real pause and not delay ? I've seen jquery's pause function but that doesn't works for me !

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my english :)